# Arrow function. To what variables the function refers to?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, arrow-functions

I am stuck on an example from a JS book. Here is an Arrow function. Works fine, but what variables the function refers to? How does it know what to do with "a, b"?

I don't understand what is going behind the scenes...

```js
const arr = [{
  name: "Suzanne"
}, {
  name: "Jim"
}, {
  name: "Trevor"
}, {
  name: "Amanda"
}];

// arr sorted reverse alphabetically 
// by second letter of name property

console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => a.name[1] < b.name[1]));
```

Comment: This is not about arrow functions. `sort` is a higher-order function, it takes a callback that gets called with two arguments. `a` and `b` can be named anything you want.

Comment: Does the book *really* have `arr.sort((a, b) => a.name[1] < b.name[1])` in it? If so, you might want a different book, as that's a completely incorrect return value for a `sort` callback... :-)

Comment: Is it though? I thought arrow functions that omit wrapping `{}`'s automatically return. Edit: it works (though I would probably sort on `name[0]` and not `name[1]`

Answer (score 4):

The values of `a` and `b` are determined by the `Array#sort` function, which is what calls your arrow function. It's the same as with normal functions; for instance, your code would work identically like this:<sup>1</sup>

```
console.log(arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.name[1] < b.name[1];
});
```

Inside `Array#sort`, you can imagine a call to your callback:

```
function Array_sort(callback) {
    // ...

    while (not_done_sorting_yet) {
        // ...
        result = callback(element[x], element[y]); // The call to your callback
        // ...code using result...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Just as with any callback (indeed, any function), it's the code *calling* it that determines what arguments it gets and their values. *(Ignoring partial application for simplicity.)*

---

<sup>1</sup> BTW: That code is wrong, the return value from the `sort` callback is supposed to be a **number**, not a boolean: `0` if `a` and `b` are equal for sorting purposes, less than zero is `a` is "less than" `b` for sorting purposes (should come before `b`), and greater than zero if `a` is "greater than" `b` for sorting purposes (should come after `b`).

Here's the correct version (for an array "sorted reverse alphabetically by second letter of name property" [from the comment in the quoted code]):

```
// Reverse alpha by second letter in name
console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => b.name[1].localeCompare(a.name[1])));
```

...since `String#localeCompare` returns an appropriate value for whether the string you call it on is "less than" or "greater than" the one you call it with. (And `name[1]` is a one-character string.)